# Tracking history using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

How could i make a batch file that would track and keep internet history (from google chrome) and after i run CCleaner and cleared history through google chrome, the batch file would have already created a text file and have the history still on it? I need this to be a batch file that would create and update a text file about this.

Batch code begins here:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to the history tracker!
echo Turn on? [1]-Yes  [2]-No
set /P variable=Enter choice:
IF "%variable%"=="1" (GOTO start)
IF "%variable%"=="2" (GOTO end)

:end
echo.

:start
REM I don't know what else to do
```

Comment: Chrome stores its History in a SQLite database, so you'd need to use a program that has a scriptable interface to SQlite to do this from batch. I'd just go with something that has already been written. [Nirsoft Chrome History View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_history_view.html)

Comment: That's going to be an absolute nightmare to write in a batch file, and most likely *far* too broad to be answered on SO, unless someone wants to really challenge themselves.

Comment: are you sure about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
:top
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%i in ('ipconfig /displaydns^|find "Record Name"') do (find "%%i" /i history.txt >nul 2>&1|| echo %%i >>history.txt)
timeout /nobreak 5 >nul 2>&1
sort history.txt /o history.txt
goto top
```

this will give you a list of all the SITES visited. not the individual pages on the sites, but the sites.

Comment: note: this will give a lot of sites, some you didnt realize you visited.